# Location is required

Tags: java, javafx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем добрый день, нужно создать модальное окно, ну вот я его как бы создаю

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setWidth(670);
stage.setHeight(551);
Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/AddChoice.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
stage.show();
```

А тут вот просто совершенно непонятное для меня с точки зрения решения исключение

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=1164:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\My work projects\MacroApp\out\production\MacroApp" macroapp.classes.StartApplication
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at macroapp.classes.Listeners.actionAddChoiceButton(Listeners.java:61)
    ... 66 more
```

А фишка в том, что путь правильный, я перепробовал всё, и final и / и в одну директорию всё кидал, ничего не помогло! Скажите, как такое решить, много в инете нашёл таких ситуаций, но никакие решения не помогли :(

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev судя по стектрейсу она возникает именно в этом коде

Comment: Судя по ошибке `FXMLLoader.load()` получил `null` от `getClass().getResource()`. Использовать относительные пути - это не очень хорошая идея. Покажите структуру каталогов проекта.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev выложил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем жесть... Ребята, если вы это видите, пишите полный путь, начиная с самого первого вашего пакета... и не забудьте / поставить в самом начале, типа так

Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/macroapp/fxml/AddChoice.fxml"));