# При запуске файла c параметрами java -jar возникает ошибка java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java

Использую jdk версии 10.0.2 и аналогичную jre
[image: jdk 10.0.2]

```
java -version
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

При компиляции в IntelliJ IDEA программа запускается без сбоев. Со следующими параметрами:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=52211:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Nik\Desktop....\ver 11\out\production\ver 3;C:\Users\Nik\Desktop...\ver 11\src\sample\sqljdbc4.jar" sample.Main

При запуске с параметром сформированного jar файла с параметром: java -jar [файл].jar выдается ошибка

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:941)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3246)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:15)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
```

Вот параметры Project Structure
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь кто-нибудь поможет, спасибо!

*Дополнительно:*

Так вызывается getResource:

```
    private void initLoader() {
    try {
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../sample/edit.fxml"));
        fxmlEdit = fxmlLoader.load();
        editDialogController = fxmlLoader.getController();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Вот содержимое jar файла
[image: jar]

Comment: Удалите свой ответ и просто исправте вопрос.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Location is required](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722562/204271)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему slash (“/”) в начале пути к файлу где-то нужен, а где-то не нужен?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/765248/204271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

исправил getResource, теперь все работает

```
fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/edit.fxml"));
```

Вместо

```
fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../sample/edit.fxml"));
```